# minimal permutation representations

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, computational-group-theory

Suppose I have a finite group $G.$ How hard is it to find the (a?) minimal degree permutation representation of $G?$ The second part of the question is: is there a table of such (hopefully for parametrized families)?

Comment: Very interesting question. I too would like to know answers . A rough attempt: Take an element of the group whose conjugacy class is *small*. The action by inner automorphisms on that class might be (should avoid central elements for obvious reasons) one possible candidate for answer.

Comment: Also, have a look at : http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02261693

Comment: @GeoffRobinson, you mean David Easdown I believe.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg :Yes, thanks, indeed I do.

Comment: Correction: In general, I don't think this is an easy problem: you might check out papers by D. Easdown and N. Saunders on Arxiv for some references.

Comment: Although this problem is very difficult in general, the answer is known in some specific cases that might be of interest. It is known for example for almost simple groups and, more generally, for (finite) groups with no nontrivial solvable normal subgroups.